# Python 'ValueError: object arrays are not supported ' when calculating single value decomposition

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror, svd

I have a numpy array:

```
matrix = array([[0,
        array([0.05385944, 0.05419472, 0.05453447])],
        [1,
         array([0.05385944, 0.05419472, 0.05453447])],
        [2,
         array([0.05385944, 0.05419472, 0.05453447])].... , 
          dtype=object)
```

I a trying to calculate the singular value decomposition using scipy.linalg like:

```
from scipy.linalg import svd
U, s, VT = svd(matrix)
```

But this gives me a value error

```
ValueError: object arrays are not supported
```

I think the issue comes from my matrix having the object datatype, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using a simple 2-dimensional matrix?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm fairly new to Python, could this matrix be converted to a 2-dimensional matrix? The 0, 1 and 2 values are just labels, so they should be separate from the other values

Comment: See [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) for details. Basically, just use `np.matrix([[first row],[second row],etc.]` In your case it would start `np.matrix([[0,0.05385944, 0.05419472, 0.05453447], [1,0.05385944, 0.05419472, 0.05453447], ...`

Comment: Is there a quick way to do this if my array goes all the way to 33, and actually has 376 elements in each of 'array([0.05385944, 0.05419472, 0.05453447....])]'. I know that's not clarified in the question, but I simplified it because the array is so large.

Comment: You should be able to write a function to do the conversion. It isn't clear just what your structure is. I haven't been able to turn it into an example that doesn't throw a syntax error (in any straightforward way).

Comment: How did you make this array in the first place?  Unless you took special steps to make an object dtype array, the component arrays probably don't all have the same shape.  A quick test would be `np.stack(matrix)`.  It will either make the desired 2d array, or throw an error.